# Parse.com user search without regex

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, parse-platform, pfquery

I have an app where I have users with a user name and a spot for their real name.  I also allow users to query to find other users.  Currently my query looks like this:

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:kCPUserName containsString:[searchText lowercaseString]];

PFQuery *userRealNameQuery = [PFUser query];
[usernameQuery whereKey:kCPUserFullName containsString: searchText];

PFQuery *userRealNameWithCapsQuery = [PFUser query];
[userRealNameWithCapsQuery whereKey:kCPUserFullName containsString:[searchText capitalizedString]];

PFQuery *userRealNameWithLowerQuery = [PFUser query];
[userRealNameWithLowerQuery whereKey:kCPUserFullName containsString:[searchText lowercaseString]];

PFQuery *finalQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[userQuery, userRealNameQuery, userRealNameWithCapsQuery, userRealNameWithLowerQuery]];
```

This works great, returning a list of users likely to match the **searchText**.  However, I've become aware that containsString uses regex, thus if I have many users searching at the same time I quickly run into the 80 regex queries / min limitation in parse.  Using **hasPrefix:** also uses regex.  The only query I can think of would be to use the **equalTo:** method, but that would mean that a user must know exactly who they are looking for and how to spell their names (either user or real).

Any suggestions?

Comment: this was why I moved away from Parse - I ended up spending loads of time coding around Parse's limits.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution to this problem was to create a separate field, call it combined_names.  This field is a concatenation of the real and user names (all lowercase).  I can then do a single regex call on this and get the same results.  While not removing all regex calls, it goes from 4 calls to 1.